# edge deformed when smooth shading is on

Tags: mesh, rigging, edges, weight-painting

Can someone please help me figure out why this happens?
I merged every single vertice on that edge, Now the automatic weights, when applied don't apply correctly to that hand as it does on the right hand.

[image]

Comment: Select your entire mesh/that part in edit Mode and try Shift + N to recalculate the normals. One reason why this is happening could be, that you scaled the hand at one point by -1 to flip it. By doing this, the normals get flipped too.

Comment: Thanks! that was it!